# Corrupt SD card on Pi but not in Windows

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-buster, corrupt

When I boot up my Pi all I get is a solid red light, not the green one. I believe this is because the SD card is corrupt, but it was working fine the other day. I put the SD card in my windows PC and it can read the contents of the top level of the first partition (it should be ~40 files and a directory), but for some reason, the Pi still won't boot. Please help, as I have important files in my home directory on the Pi?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have the correct power supply for your RPi. I've experienced this issue before using a power supply that didn't have have the proper amperage.

Comment: *"put the SD card in my windows PC and it can read the SD card fine"* -> No, it can't.  It can read the 1st partition, but that is only a few hundred MB.  Most of the card is the second partition, which cannot be read on Windows without you installing special third party software.  So this is not an indication that everything is fine.  You should, however, edit into the question the contents of the top level of the first partition (it should be ~40 files and a directory).

Comment: Is there a screen attached to the PI? it might give extra information about where it fails to boot.

Comment: @PMFThe screen just stays white. No booting up even occurs.

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: So it seems the SD card is corrupt. I can use other SD cards and they work fine, it just seems to be this one. How would I go about recovering my data, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep what is on the SD Card **DO NOT attempt to "fix" it**.

Mount the card in an adapter (on the Pi or any Linux computer) and copy your files.